# Change Microsoft WPF Ribbon Controller to Windows Store App Design

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am developing an application with WPF. I added the Microsoft Ribbon control to my XMAL UI page, but its style is similar more to the Office 2010 design than the Office 2013 one. I'd like something that adheres more to the Windows Store App design principles. Is there a way to change it?

Comment: I think it would be quite difficult, unless you are expert in XAML and WPF. There are other controls, but not all of them free.

Answer (score 0):

It's a WPF control, so yes.
You have two options, either you play around with the control's style, to make it look slightly different, changes brushes, etc ...
Or you modify its control template, to completely reorganise it.